# Log message from Class library which is used in Azure function

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions

In an Azure function I am able to add logs and it is added to function logs as expected. Below is sample code

```
[FunctionName("myfunction")]

        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequestMessage req, ILogger log)
        {
           log.LogInformation("HTTP trigger function start");  // This works fine
           MyClass class1 = new MyClass(); // this is from a class library referred in the function
           class1.mymethod()
         }
```

In the `MyClass` methods I want to log messages the same way I did in azure function. I tried creating a new log object of type `Ilogger` in my class library and calling `LogInformation` method with the required messages. But this is not working and I am getting error like "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'logger') at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerExtensions.Log"

So how we need to create new object of logger in class library so that it will log message to the same Azure function logs.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. It seems like you should be able to pass the `ILogger` from your Azure function to the classes you instantiate. Is there a reason you cannot do that?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to create a logger that will log to "Azure Function Logs". You'll have to pass around the `log` object as Andy said. Not a C# expert so don't know but IIRC sysout and syserror also are collected by App Insights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, add a `PackageReference` for [`Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/)* to your class library project. Then, add a parameter to your class' constructor that accepts an `ILogger` (or an `ILogger<YourClass>` if you intend on using DI). Store the logger in a field and then use it when you need it.

```cs
public class MyClass {
   private readonly ILogger _logger;
   public MyClass(ILogger logger) =>
      _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));

   public void MyMethod(string name) {
      _logger.LogInformation("Hello {Person}", name);
   }
}
```

Then, pass the logger to your constructor.

```cs
FunctionName("myfunction")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequestMessage req, ILogger log) {
   log.LogInformation("HTTP trigger function start");
   var class1 = new MyClass(log);
   class1.MyMethod("pinkfloydx33");
}
```

You can also make the logger *optional* by substituting [`NullLogger.Instance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.abstractions.nulllogger.instance?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#Microsoft_Extensions_Logging_Abstractions_NullLogger_Instance) (or [`NullLogger<MyClass>.Instance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.abstractions.nulllogger-1.instance?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)) when one is not provided by the user:

```cs
public class MyClass {
   private readonly ILogger _logger;
   public MyClass(ILogger logger = null) =>
      _logger = logger ?? NullLogger.Instance;
   //.... 
}
```

Then you don't need to perform any null checks around your logging statements.

* **Note** that the latest version of Azure Functions only run on .NET Core 3.1. This means you can only reference the 3.x line of the Nuget package in your class library, and *not* the 5.x versions. While it will technically compile, the functions runtime/host will throw `TypeInitializationException` at runtime. Unfortunately as .NET5 is not LTS there won't be a new version of Azure Functions until .NET6. If you want to use your library from Azure Functions as well as "normal" projects targeted at .NET5, you'll have to cross-compile the library.

Comment: How can we access logger through DI? What if we can't pass logger in the constructor?